# Moving a pinhole camera

Tags: geometry

First of all, I should say all my information on pinhole camera is only 1 day old, so I'm not sure if anything that I say is correct or not. But lets assume that I have a point on the image plane and a set of world points. I want to find out if any of my world points will match my point on the image plane if I move my camera from point A to B.

I don't know if this approach is possible or not, but I thought if I calculate the plane containing 3 points (A, B, point in image plane), I can calculate distance of world points from this plane and find out if any of these points will be seen during transition from A to B.

What do you think? Is my approach correct? In addition, I will be happy to have some good reference over pinhole cameras.

Comment: I found this [reference](https://hedivision.github.io/Pinhole.html#:~:text=The%20simplest%20camera%20model%20is%20pinhole%20model%20which,is%20called%20the%20image%20plane%20or%20focal%20plane.)

Comment: @LexiBelleFan I have seen this. Everything I find is as short as this one on internet and almost no one discuss movement of camera. Translation comes a lot, but in reality translation is not that useful if you don't know the match happens during move from `A` to `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pinhole camera model is the simplest model of a perspective projection camera.  In this model, the camera has a coordinate frame represented by a translation vector $d$ and a rotation matrix $R$ whose columns are the unit directions of the three axes.  If $r(x,y,z)$ is a point expressed in world coordinates (relative to the absolute frame) and $p(x',y',z')$ is this same point but expressed in the camera coordinate frame then

$ r = d + R p $

So

$ p = R^T (r - d) $

In the pinhole camera model, a projection plane is created at the plane $ z' = f $ where $f $ is a positive constant.  Given a point $r_1(x_1, y_1, z_1) $ then its image on the projection plane is generated as follows.  Connect $r_1$ to the origin (which is $d$) and intersect this line with the projection plane.

Equation of this line of sight between $d$ and $r_1$ is

$r(t) = d + t (r_1 - d) $

Now the projection plane equation is $z' = f$, using this information, we can determine the value of $t$ that gives the intersection of the line of sight with the projection plane, simply by setting the $z'$ coordinate of $r(t)$ to $f$.

$p = R^T (r(t) - d) $, so $ p = t R^T (r_1 - d ) $. Setting the third coordinate to $f$ gives

$ t = \dfrac{f}{k^T R^T (r1 - d ) } $

where $k^T = [0, 0, 1] $
Thus the image is

$ p = \dfrac{f R^T (r_1 - d)} { k^T R^T (r_1 - d) } \hspace{15pt}(*) $

The coordinate of $p$ are the image coordinates on the projection plane.  Since the projection plane in reality is not infinite but bounded, we can assume that its bounds are the region $[-x_0, x_0] \times [-y_0, y_0 ]$.

Then we can determine if a world point is visible through the image boundaries by calculating $p$ directly using equation $(*)$

Comment: Thanks, this is great. But I don't think being visible via image boundary necessarily means that the point will be visible with specific movement of camera. because the world point may not be visible in the image boundary but if we move camera more, it may become visible.

Comment: Yes.  Of course.

Comment: Then this practically does not solve my problem completely. Because I want to know if the world point will become visible in specific point of image if I move camera between 2 points.

Comment: At the destination location and orientation of the camera, calculate the $p$ vector using equation $(*)$, then you can determine if $p$ is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I can check start and end point using this method. But what about a point in middle of camera movement? I cannot. The only way that comes to my mind with your method is to calculate `p` for start and end of camera movement, then find the line connecting these 2 points. Now if point that I want is on this line,  I guess I can say that in this camera movement, I can see that world point.

Comment: All you have to do then is express $d$ as follows: $ d = d_A + s (d_B - d_A) $ and plug this $d$ in the formula $(*)$, then vector $p$ will be a function of $s$ (where $0 \le s \le 1$).  Now you can do whatever you want with the vector $p$.

Comment: In all cases above, I believe you should be using the inverse of $R$, which is denoted $R^{-1}$, instead of the transpose $R^T$, since $R^{-1}*R=I$.

Comment: Oh I forgot that all rotation matrices have $det R = 1$, which happens if and only if $R^{-1}=R^T$ :D